# Best practice on Local/Mage module

Tags: module, overrides, third-party-module

I have a developer who is saying we don't need to bother to convert a local/Mage module that does not override core to a local/Module namespace. I was under the assumption we should never user local/Mage and we have started to convert everything? Are we wasting out time. For example many third party payment module use the Mage namespace and put their code in the local directory. (Linkpoint, USAePay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically I don't see any problems keeping 3rd party modules in `local/Mage`. Keeping your socks in the glove box of your car doesn't cause much problem either neither sense.

Good question by the way.

Comment: Technically though its not sound, if I want to make a minor adjustment to 3rd party code and just want a quick override, with it living in the `local` codepool, I can't. just means i'm overwriting their base code, come upgrade time of said module, i'm back to spaghetti code. :)

Comment: Good valid point. It's like you jumped out of bed in the morning and realized that all your socks are in a glove box of your car.